How to run selenium browser in invisible (or minimized mode) with python on Windows PC?
Is there anyone who can help with how to run selenium browser in invisible (or minimized mode) with python on Windows PC? I need to create a program to get the name of patent from the website of EPO (European patent office) only with given application number. First I tried to use requests module to send get request at this address but there wasn't any information about the patent in the response. In the internet I found info that the reason for this is that the page is dynamic and a browser is needed to load the full page content.
I tried this and it loads the patent name correctly but there is one pop up Chrome browser window above my program, which I want to hide (make invisible or minimize). Can anyone help on this with python on Windows PC?
from selenium import webdriver
import re

ep_number = 3624475
application_number = 19183545

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless") # I tried also with "--headless=new" and "--no-startup-window" but it doesn't helped
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
# browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("https://register.epo.org/application?number=EP" + str(application_number))
browser.implicitly_wait(10) # I am waiting the page to be loaded correctly (not sure is it required or not)

en_name = re.findall(rf"(?<=EP{ep_number}\s-\s)[\S\s]*?(?=</a>)", browser.page_source)[0] # using this to find the name of the patent in the result page

browser.quit()

print(en_name)


What is ep_number here? You haven't declared

@SuramuthuR I forgot to copy this variable from my code. Now you can see it (i edited the question).

The option --headless alone will stop Chrome from rendering full screen. But that's not your real problem.
That website blocks the use of "automated tools".
Here is the proof:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions

options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")

application_number = 19183545
url = f"https://register.epo.org/application?number=EP{application_number}"

with webdriver.Chrome(options=options) as driver:
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    driver.get(url)
    selector = By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.epoContentWrap.clearfix.en_locale p"
    for p in driver.find_elements(*selector):
        print(p.text)

Output:
The European Patent Register application has found that requests from your IP address may be in violation of our fair use charter.
European Patent Register may reject your requests if you are using any automated tools, perform too many queries per minute or generate queries that result in the system attempting to retrieve unusually large numbers of documents.
Please note that multiple users behind a firewall may be seen as a single user who apparently generates many queries in a short time or who downloads excessive amounts of data. As a result it is possible that a colleague other than the user who triggered the error will receive a rejection message.
If you feel the rejection is not warranted and you would like us to investigate it, please contact us and send us

We will analyse the information you send us and if necessary contact your IT department to try to resolve the situation.
For more information please click on the "terms and conditions of use for European Patent Register " link at the bottom of the home page.

Note:
Also tested with the 3rd party undetected_chromedriver module with the same result

It's not ethical to try programatically even if it were possible I guess. Because the url https://register.epo.org/application?number=EP19183545 initially lands in a page which verifies if you are human.
Following the ethics is very important for any professionals.
But you can very well check manually.

